# There are error about ffmpeg in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

```
from ffmpy import FFmpeg
import ffmpy

ff = FFmpeg(inputs={'screenrecord.mp4':None},
            outputs={'C:\\Users\pc\Desktop\CM\03.24\Demo\output.mp4':None})

#ff.cmd
ff.run()
```

following is the error message.

```
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/pc/Desktop/CM/03.24/Demo/Demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ffmpy-0.2.2-py3.6.egg\ffmpy.py", line 95, in run
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 系统找不到指定的文件。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/CM/03.24/Demo/Demo.py", line 8, in <module>
    ff.run()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ffmpy-0.2.2-py3.6.egg\ffmpy.py", line 99, in run
ffmpy.FFExecutableNotFoundError: Executable 'ffmpeg' not found
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: FFmpeg package for python is just a wrapper for `ffmpeg`, you still need application itself. Error message  clearly states this in the error - `Executable 'ffmpeg' not found`

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Path to ffmpeg can be provided in following way to resolve the error:

```
import ffmpy

ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(executable='C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe', inputs={'speech.mp3': None},
                      outputs={'speech.wav': None})
ff.run()
```

Please note the example code above is for Windows, for Linux you have to use corresponding path with ffmpeg without exe.